# Jupyter QtPython Errors

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, seaborn

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns;

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips.head()

tips['tip_pct'] = 100 * tips['tip'] / tips['total_bill']
grid = sns.FacetGrid(tips, row="sex", col="time", margin_titles=True)
grid.map(plt.hist, "tip_pct", bins=np.linspace(0, 40, 15));
```

When I run the above code in Spyder IDE (Anaconda Navigator's Package), I get the desired results. But when the same code is run in Jupter QtConsole (including the line: %matplotlib inline) I get the following errors:

**Out:**

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-c7ea1bbe0c80> in <module>()
----> 1 grid.map(plt.hist, "tip_pct", bins=np.linspace(0, 40, 15));

/Users/waqas/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in map(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
701 
702             # Get the current axis
--> 703             ax = self.facet_axis(row_i, col_j)
704 
705             # Decide what color to plot with

/Users/waqas/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in facet_axis(self, row_i, col_j)
832 
833         # Get a reference to the axes object we want, and make it active
--> 834         plt.sca(ax)
835         return ax
836 

/Users/waqas/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in sca(ax)
905             m.canvas.figure.sca(ax)
906             return
--> 907     raise ValueError("Axes instance argument was not found in a figure.")
908 
909 

ValueError: Axes instance argument was not found in a figure.
```

I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat related...I was getting the same error when running jupyter notebook because I was running the following lines in separate cells.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=titanic,col='sex')
g.map(plt.hist,'age')
```

Once I ran them both in the same cell the image displayed properly.

Since you're using Qt console see if it helps to assign your mapping to grid.

```
grid = grid.map(plt.hist, "tip_pct", bins=np.linspace(0, 40, 15))
```

You'll see the same approach is used in the [documentation for FacetGrid](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid).